# TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create a custom user model for my project

**model.py**

```
class ShopkeeperRegTable(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
uu = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50,default=None,null=True)
email = models.CharField(_('email address'), max_length=200, unique=True)
phone_number = models.BigIntegerField(unique=True)
enable_wp = models.BooleanField(default=False)
bucket = models.CharField(null=True, blank=True, max_length=200)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
created_on = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True, blank=True)
last_login = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['first_name','phone_number']

objects = CustomUserManager()

def __str__(self):
    return self.email
```

**CustomUserManager()**

```
class CustomUserManager(BaseUserManager):
"""
Custom user model manager where email is the unique identifiers
for authentication instead of usernames.
"""
def create_superuser(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a SuperUser with the given email and password.
    """
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', True)

    if extra_fields.get('is_staff') is not True:
        raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_staff=True.'))
    if extra_fields.get('is_superuser') is not True:
        raise ValueError(_('Superuser must have is_superuser=True.'))
    return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

def create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
    """
    Create and save a User with the given email and password.
    """
    if not email:
        raise ValueError(_('The Email must be set'))
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save()
    return user
```

**serializer.py**

```
enter class ShopkeeperRegTableSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
    model = ShopkeeperRegTable
    fields = "__all__"
    extra_kwargs = {
        'password' : {'write_only':True}
    }
def create(self, validated_data):
    passwd = validated_data.pop('password', None)
    instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
    if passwd is not None:
        instance.set_password(passwd)
    instance.save()
    return instancehere
```

**view.py**

```
from api.account.serializer import ShopkeeperRegTableSerializer
```

#in code Imports
from api.account.authutils import Utils

class ShopkeeperRegTableCreate(APIView):
permission_classes = [AllowAny]

```
def post(self, request):
    req_serializer = ShopkeeperRegTableSerializer(data=request.data)
    if req_serializer.is_valid():
        print("coming her")
        new_user = req_serializer.save()
        print("coming here")
        if new_user:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(req_serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

but its showing error while posting via postman

```
coming her
```

Internal Server Error: /api/account/signup/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarenv\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarenv\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 70, in view
return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
raise exc
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarside_retailer\api\account\views.py", line 32, in post
new_user = req_serializer.save()
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarenv\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\serializers.py", line 205, in save
self.instance = self.create(validated_data)
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarside_retailer\api\account\serializer.py", line 16, in create
instance = self.Meta.model(**validated_data)
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 498, in **init**
_setattr(self, prop, kwargs[prop])
File "C:\Users\beher\Desktop\Bazarside\bazarside_on_rest\bazarenv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 545, in **set**
raise TypeError(
TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use groups.set() instead.[postman error logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgI5K.jpg)

Comment: Do you assign an user to a group somewhere in your code ?

Comment: no but in migration folder its automatically generated


            model_name='shopkeeperregtable',
            name='groups',
            field=models.ManyToManyField(blank=True, help_text='The groups this user belongs to. A user will get all permissions granted to each of their groups.', related_name='user_set', related_query_name='user', to='auth.Group', verbose_name='groups'),
        ),